# How to list content of .Trashes folder in single-user mode

Tags: macos, trash

Is `.Trashes` folder suppose to be empty when computer is launched in single-user mode. If not, how do I see its contents? I tried `ls` command, but it doesn't list anything. It could be that the Trash simply is empty, but due to an error I am working on, I cannot login into my user account to check it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a systemwide Trash folder as well as one per user. If you deleted files in Finder while being logged in with your user account, the deleted files are in `/Users/YOUR-USER-NAME/.Trash`.

Answer (score 2):

The command I use while in normal mode is `sudo ls -a /.Trashes` and in single-user mode you don't need to use `sudo`.

On my system, `/.Trashes` is empty however `~/.Trash` is not empty as I have files in my Trash.

On external volumes `.Trashes` in the root of the volume has directories, one for each `$EUID` and within those directories are the files deleted, on each volume, by each User.